# How can one open an activity from service faster?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service

I'm having an issue with activity launching from the service. It opens the activity with some sort of delay (1sec or so), is there a way to speed things up, just like the window of device administrator pops up almost momentarily? or maybe show some preloader?

Thanks

Comment: Use Traceview and determine where your time is being spent.

Comment: The thing is that I'm trying to load an activity with the default layout, I've also tried to load activity without setting the layout and it still takes too much time to pop the activity

Comment: So? Use Traceview and determine where your time is being spent. Only when you know where your time is being spent will you have any hope of actually reducing it.

Comment: I've used traceview and debugger and it shows waitForActivityStart where it waits for the object, any way to surpass it?

Comment: Since I cannot find anything named "waitForActivityStart" in the current Android source code, I have no idea what to tell you, sorry.